# Fixing a Cross App Scripting Vulnerability

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, webview, google-play-console

Cтолкнулся с этой проблемой. В приложение используется Webview, у которого стоят интент-фильтры для открытия приложения по ссылке. Соответственно первое решение поставить exported = false не представляется возможным, как быть?

```
в onCreate
        webViewSettings.displayZoomControls = true
        webViewSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webViewSettings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webViewSettings.databaseEnabled = true
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface,"JSInterfaceDev")

в Manifeste
            android:name=".webView.WebViewActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">

            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="http"
                    android:host="${hostName}" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="${hostName}" />
            </intent-filter>
```

> **Fixing a Cross App Scripting Vulnerability**.
>   **What’s happening**.
>   One or more of your apps contain a WebView Cross-App Scripting issue which can allow malicious apps to steal user cookies and other data. Please refer to the notice on your Play Console. After the deadlines shown in your Play Console, any apps that contain unfixed security vulnerabilities may be removed from Google Play.
>
> **Action required​ **.
>   1. Sign in to your Play Console, and navigate to the Alerts section to see which apps are affected and the deadlines to resolve these issues.
>   2. Update your affected apps and fix the vulnerability.
>   3. Submit the updated versions of your affected apps.
>   Upon resubmission, your app will be reviewed again. This process can take several hours. If the app passes review and is published successfully, then no further action is required. If the app fails review, then the new app version will not be published and you will receive an email notification.
>
> **Additional details**.
>   WebViews that enable JavaScript and load data read from untrusted Intents can be tricked by malicious apps into executing JavaScript code in an unsafe context. We recommend that you prevent this vulnerability in one of the following ways:
>
> **Option 1: Ensure that affected activities are not exported**.
>
> Find any Activities with affected WebViews. If these Activities do not need to take Intents from other apps you can set android:exported=false for the Activities in your Manifest. This ensures that malicious apps cannot send harmful inputs to any WebViews in these Activities.
>
> **Option 2: Protect WebViews in exported activities**.
>
> If you want to set an Activity with an affected WebView as exported then we recommend that you make the following changes:
>
> 1. Update your targetSdkVersion.
>      Ensure that your targetSdkVersion meets Google Play’s target API level requirement. Apps with a targetSdkVersion of 16 or lower evaluate JavaScript URLs passed to loadUrl in the currently loaded page context. Targeting SDK version 16 or lower and calling loadUrl using unsanitized input from untrusted Intents lets attackers execute harmful scripts in the affected WebView.
> 2. Protect calls to evaluateJavascript.
>      Ensure that parameters to evaluateJavascript are always trusted. Calling evaluateJavascript using unsanitized input from untrusted Intents lets attackers execute harmful scripts in the affected WebView.
> 3. Prevent unsafe file loads.
>      Ensure that affected WebViews cannot load the cookie database. WebViews that load unsanitized file:// URLs from untrusted Intents can be attacked by malicious apps in the following way. A malicious web page can write  tags into the cookies database and then a malicious app can send an Intent with a file:// URL pointing to your WebView cookies database. The malicious script will execute if the cookies database is loaded in a WebView and can steal session information.
>      You can ensure that affected WebViews cannot load the WebView cookies database in two ways. You can either disable all file access or you can verify that any loaded file:// URLs point to safe files. Note that an attacker can use a symbolic link to trick checks on the URL path. To prevent such an attack, be sure to check the canonical path of any untrusted file:// URL before loading instead of just checking the URL path.